# event bubbling in react

Tags: reactjs, events

I am doing a React project.

However, there is one question.

I try to manage the links in the page from one place.

For example,

if page have an external link, open a new window,

if it is a link of the same site, 
it tries to move from the inside.

so,

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const target = e.target;
      const aLink = target.closest('a');

      if (aLink && aLink.getAttribute('href')) {
        const href = aLink.getAttribute('href') || '';
        if (href) {
          if (isExternalLink(href)) {
            window.open(href);
            e.preventDefault();
          } else if (isOurLink(href)) {
            //
          } else {
            //
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  :
```

I want to do this.

Is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: Its probably better to write an HOC that manages the click behaviour and restrict it to within the component instead of allowing it to bubble up till the dom, since it might get difficult to debug with component architecture

Comment: Do you have control over the html of the links? In that case I would just use `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"` to them not a bit deal and I always would prefer allowing the browser to behave in a default way over trying to take control if it's not necessary. "Bubbling" also doesn't work in a normal way in react, all events are on the document body and bubbling is done synthetically, this can have some unexpected edge case behaviour.

Comment: The a link that contains the content written in the WYSIWYG editor is a problem.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri  Thank you for your advice.
Can you give me some more details on how to use HOC?
Here's how I think.
   "class ExtLink extends Link {
   }"

Is that right?

Comment: @user1920486 `"class ExtLink extends Link { }" ` is inheritance, please check https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: @Shubham Khatri Thank you. Is this what you said? Please review once I understand what I understand. "export default ExtLink = withLink(Link); const withLink = (Wrap) => { return class {. ..render(){ return (<Wrap .../>); }}".....import ExtLink from  "./ExtLink";...

Comment: yes this is what I meant

Comment: @Shubham Khatri thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your react component while rendering anchor links can call a service, this service can check wether a url is internal or external. Using this information you can render using something like this...

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    var openInNewTab = someService.IsInternal(props.someUrl);
    return (
        <a href={props.someUrl} target={openInNewTab ? '_blank': ''}>
        </a>
    );
}
```

As already mentioned in comments, perhaps an HOC is more suited for this.

Comment: Thank you for your advice...Can you give me some more details?